# Unable to increase timeout value ,with pxssh

Tags: python

I am trying to run a command over ssh session.
This command is taking more than 1hr. to complete(installing few file sets).
Now My script is able to start the command,but,it is failing after few mins,with this below error msg.

> File "./return.py", line 32, in CHECKFILESTATUS
> s.logout()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/pexpect/pxssh.py",
> line 350, in logout
> index = self.expect([EOF, "(?i)there are stopped jobs"])   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/pexpect/spawnbase.py",
> line 321, in expect
> timeout, searchwindowsize, async)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/pexpect/spawnbase.py",
> line 345, in expect_list
> return exp.expect_loop(timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/pexpect/expect.py",
> line 107, in expect_loop
> return self.timeout(e)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/pexpect/expect.py",
> line 70, in timeout
> raise TIMEOUT(msg) pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded. <pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x3fff8e63a9d0> command: /bin/ssh args:
> ['/bin/ssh', '-q', '-l', 'xxxx', 'sys'] buffer (last 100 chars):
> 'eement acceptance. You can view the license file details in the
> /ITM/LAP/license directory\r\n' before (last 100 chars): 'eement
> acceptance. You can view the license file details in the
> /ITM/LAP/license directory\r\n' after: <class
> 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'> match: None match_index: None
> exitstatus: None flag_eof: False pid: 4289 child_fd: 5 closed: False
> timeout: 30 delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'> logfile: None
> logfile_read: None logfile_send: None maxread: 2000 ignorecase: False
> searchwindowsize: None delaybeforesend: 0.05 delayafterclose: 0.1
> delayafterterminate: 0.1 searcher: searcher_re:
> 0: EOF
> 1: re.compile("(?i)there are stopped jobs").

Code:

```
#!/bin/python
import pexpect
import netrc
from pexpect import pxssh,TIMEOUT

LPAR = 'VI'
secrets = netrc.netrc()
ID, MC, PD = secrets.authenticators( LPAR )
hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')

def CHECKFILESTATUS(command):
global hostname
global ID
global PD

    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        hostname = hostname
        username = ID
        password = PD
        s.login(hostname, username, password)
        s.sendline(command)
        s.prompt()
        print s.before
        s.logout()
    except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
        print("pxssh failed on login.")
        print(e)


def main():
CHECKFILESTATUS('updateios -dev /mnt/V -install -accept')


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Any suggestion to resolve this time-out issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=7200)
```

Should do the trick

Looking at the source, the `pxssh` constructor takes `timeout` as a keyword argument and sets the timeout(I'm guessing in seconds).

> def **init** (self, timeout=30, maxread=2000, searchwindowsize=None,
>                       logfile=None, cwd=None, env=None, ignore_sighup=True, echo=True,
>                       options={}, encoding=None, codec_errors='strict'):

Comment: Hey,it worked for me.Thanks for your quick response. :)

Comment: No problemo, please accept the answer if it helped you, so others can benefit as well.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue for me. Set the timeout to 1 second, still takes around 30 seconds to realize it can't connect